# Enable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration via Registry?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I need turn on Internet Enhanced Security feature, and need to do so using entries in the registry.

In my server this is working fine, I have tried to fine the relevant paths in the registry without any luck.

I have changed some information but on the PC where I want add the Internet Enhanced Security feature, these changes have not had any effect.

What registry changes are needed to enable IE Enhanced Security Configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The IE 
These are the values I set to make sure the IE Enhanced Security Configuration is disabled on my terminal servers.  To enable it, I believe you just need to use a value of 1 instead of 0 for both settings.

```
Hive HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
Key path Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings 
Value name IEHardenIENoWarn 
Value type REG_DWORD 
Value data 0x0 (0) 


Hive HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
Key path Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap 
Value name IEHarden 
Value type REG_DWORD 
Value data 0x0 (0)
```

Refs:

- [kb933991](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933991)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/06/23/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-on-windows-2003-server-silently.aspx